# Any syntax highlighting for VimL now that highlight.js is the new standard for SO/SE?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I noticed that there isn't (as far as I'm aware) any syntax highlighting for VimL as of now.

Now that Google prettify is replaced with highlight.js, wouldn't it be possible to have one now?

Comment: It would be, but their immediate plan doesn't include adding new languages. Just parity with the existing set.

Comment: Kinda sad, given it doesn't look too hard to add support for a new syntax highlighting (though I'm not a javascript developer, so i guess i can't be sure).

Comment: It won't be, but when you're making such a big change, it's best to limit the scope of the initial change.

Comment: Yeah, make sense. Maybe someone can make a list of all the non-supported langs to add to the syntax highlighting, so it might have more interest to get added (than just adding support for VimL alone i mean).

Comment: I also remember reading that the rollout for other sites will happen after the rollout for SO

Comment: It's currently only rolled out to meta.se and meta.so. Rest of the network gets the changes on Sept 24th.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very disappointingly for us, although part of [the rationale for changing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter?cb=1) from Prettify to highlight.js was that with Prettify "no new language syntaxes are being supported", the current change does *not* add highlighting for Vimscript or any other "new" languages.

Worse than that, if these moderator comments are to believed, it sounds as though SE intends to be conservative about adding new languages in the future (emphasis mine):

> I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but this update has not added any new language support (officially. Technically sublanguages like Less/scss got snuck in with the css support). […] That being said, adding more languages to our bundle is technically trivial, **but we need to be mindful of bloating the deliverable size. I'll keep this suggestion in mind once we revisit and decide whether to add additional language support.** [— Ben Kelly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter?cb=1#comment1183352_354029)

> **In theory, yes.** That being said, I've not looking into the possibilities there or how it would impact us (from a bandwidth/hosting perspective) or our users (from a UX/performance perspective). This is definitely something we'll keep in mind **if we decide to expand our supported languages in the future.** [— Ben Kelly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter?cb=1#comment1183530_354029)